# starting again the latest process within loop if specific condition isn't met

Tags: bash, programming

```
for (( j=1; j <= i; j++ ))
do
# process something as sequential within loop #
if [ ! -f specific_file_$id ]; then
echo " Necessary File not found! "
echo " starting the current process again for the last time "

fi
done
```

In this loop, if `specific_file_$id` (w.r.t loop step) isn't created after the process I need to repeat the related process within loop for the last time. If the repeated process still cannot create the file, I should go to the next process within loop. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand exactly what you're asking. If a file is not found you want to repeat the process you've just done once, on the same file, then move on to the next iteration of the loop?

Comment: yes it is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To attempt to answer your question, following your comments, you could probably include the process which you want to repeat within the `if` statement, this of course depends on what those processes are doing:

```
for (( j=1; j <= i; j++ ))
do
# process something as sequential within loop #
if [ ! -f specific_file_$id ]; then
echo " Necessary File not found! "
echo " starting the current process again for the last time "
# process responsible for the creation of specific_file_$id #
fi
done
```

As the `if` statement is only triggered if the file doesn't exist, you can repeat the part of the process responsible for the file creation, this will use any variables set within that particular iteration. Once the `if` statement has completed, the `for` loop will continue on its next iteration, any further files which aren't created will be treated in the same way.

Comment: you exactly got the problem right. I couldn't create the structure with continue and break within the loop. Could you give me an example?

Comment: It's really difficult without more information on what you're doing, but I'll try.

Comment: try to imagine, 4 consecutive loops, first 2 loops create the necessary file so there is no problem but third loop cannot create the file so I need to run the third loop again. If the second run of the third loop still cannot create the file I can be able to continue the run for the forth loop (otherwise it would cause infinite loop).

Comment: I've tried to answer, but again, without looking at what your code actually does, it's very difficult. The question may well be closed as unclear.